# Javascript Redirect still active

Tags: javascript, html

I have been recently working on a website for myself, http://retrixsolutions.pw/, and I have a process before which loaded my website and redirected it to another page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.location = "homepage.html";
</script>
```

Using this script, it automatically redirected my websites' index.html to homepage.html

I then looked into another website design and decided I liked that one better. I removed the files on my CentOS webserver and then uploaded the new ones. These files do not require me to redirect.

If you go to http://retrixsolutions.pw/ it works, but if you go to http://retrixsolutions.pw/index.html, it redirects to another page even though the script to redirect is completely removed.

I have restarted my webserver, shut it down and then re-uploaded the files but still the index.html file relocates to homepage.html.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's probably caching the older file. If you restart the webserver, does it start working? Also, try clearing your browser cache while you're at it.

Comment: I'm not being redirected. Try refreshing *your* browser.

Comment: Maybe it's cached

Comment: Thanks for the help, my browser seemed to cache the old file, sorry for being such an idiot :)

Comment: You should really try clearing your browser cache.
In Chrome just press Ctrl-Shift-Delete ...

Comment: You can use un-cached browsers, like Epic and Chrome Incognito Mode

Comment: Another way is use the CTRL+Shift+R keys for reload a page... this will ignore the cache.

Answer (score 1):

What you'd need to do is make sure your browser is not caching the files. Caching is essentially the browser saving time and effort, and it saves a local copy of the file to its storage, which means that if you boot up that page, it will load the saved file, even if the file online changes. To clear cache, you can refresh the page, hard refresh and clear cache, or use an incognito or private browser (such as [Epic](http://epicbrowser.com))

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to what JBDouble05 said, another easy way to clear your cache is to hold `Shift` while clicking the refresh button.

Comment: I wrote an answer since I do not have enough rep to comment xD

Comment: Now you have enough reputation!

Comment: 1 Minute later ---- Wut... Now I can comment xD

Comment: Oh no. Hey, could you vote up my answer if you liked it? (or was that you already?)